# How to create a hansdshake for Jenkins when assumeing an IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have a desired workflow that looks something like this.

Terraform stored in Bitbucket.
Push triggers, Jenkins job. (Bur default IAM Role for Jenkins agents can't do some things. Like write IAM objects).

I want to create a role that that my Jenkins box can assume, but only if the pusher of the code is verified in someway. Bitbucket does not do GPG keys.

I feel there should be something in the Roles Trust Relationship that I can't spoof via the script that is a handshake between the Bitbucket commit and the role assumption.

I just cant put my finger on what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

Keep in mind that, in git, committing code and pushing it are two different actions which can be performed by different users.  A user can push code which has been committed by any other user.

However, Jenkins is only aware of commit authors, not the user who pushed those commits to Bitbucket.  Furthermore, in git, commit authors/e-mails can be spoofed.  So Jenkins can never be 100% sure of either who committed the code or who pushed it.

For our Terraform repo, we solve this issue by limiting the users who are allowed to merge into the main branch (those who are unauthorized need to open a PR).  And of course only pushes to the main branch trigger a Terraform run.